# Is the Keras's default LSTM unrolled or stateful?

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

In the Keras documentation, both `stateful` and `unroll` are set to `False`. So how is the recurrent done in Keras if it's neither of these? 
[Keras RNN documentaion](https://keras.io/layers/recurrent/)

I have checked the source code for RNN in Keras, it seems that the default action is to initialize the LSTM at every time step. Am I worng?

```py
       if initial_state is not None:
            pass
       elif self.stateful:
            initial_state = self.states
       else:
            initial_state = self.get_initial_state(inputs)
```

If I was correct, does it mean that, for time series analysis, it would be better to set `unroll=True` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Neither unrolled nor stateful.

Remember that "stateful" in Keras means only that "two consecutive batches will be interpreted as two parts of the **same** sequences". Nothing else. (Batch 2 is a sequel of batch 1)

All LSTM's, of course, have states (it's impossible not to).

Be careful with the expression "initialize the LSTM". A `stateful=False` layer will "reset states" for every batch. The practical result is: "each batch is a group of individual sequences from start to end". (Batch 2 is not a sequel of batch 1)

"States" are information about the "history of a sequence up to the current step". They are completely different from "weights", which are what the layer actually learned from all sequences.

"Unroll" is a way to transform the recurrent calculations into a single graph without recurrency. It's meant only for short sequences, it gets faster processing at the expense of using more memory.